# Null value on updating column value during migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add a new column `slug` to an existing table `devices` and assign random unique values to it.

The following is my migration script.

```php
public function up()
    {

        Schema::table('devices', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->string('slug');
        });

        $ids = DB::table('devices')->where('slug','')->pluck('id');

        //dd($ids);
        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
            Device::whereId($id[0])->update(array('slug' => uniqid()));
        }


    }
```

The migration is running perfectly. But the slug field is an empty string after the migration. But it should be a unique string.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem with loop, try this:

```php
foreach ($ids as $id)
{
    Device::whereId($id)->update(array('slug' => uniqid()));
}
```

Also, you can make simpler

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('devices', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->string('slug');
    });

    Device::update(['slug' => uniqid()]);
}
```